# How a JAR file running in android calls a executable file running on Windows?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, executable, android-uiautomator

I'm perform some tests with **uiautomator** and after the device makes some steps, I need to measure the current of it. 
The problem is: I run the .jar file inside the android and it needs to call the Windows Terminal to run the executable file.

How can I do that?

The tests are something like this:

```
UiScrollable uisAppViews = new UiScrollable(
        new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

uisAppViews.setAsHorizontalList();

UiObject uioSettingsApp = uisAppViews
        .getChildByText(new UiSelector()
                .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()),
                "Settings");
uioSettingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    UiObject uioSettingsValidation = new UiObject(new     
                    UiSelector().packageName("com.android.settings"));
    if(uioSettingsValidation.exists())
        return true;
    else{
        assertTrue("Unable to detect Settings", uioSettingsValidation.exists()); 
        return false;
    }
    //HERE I NEED TO RUN THE CURRENT MEASURE EXECUTABLE FILE.
```

Maybe some library to perform this comunication...
or some *jerry-rig*....

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: A windows executable on called by a Dalvik VM on Android *Linux*? A bit painful, don't you think?

Comment: I know... I know... Nobody says It'was easy! rs... That's cause I really dont have an alternative... :/

Comment: Do you really not have an alternative? Is another Linux version of the executable available? Perhaps the source? Or can it be reimplemented in Java?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any other alternative, cause this software came to me as a executable file and it doesn't have another implementation... :/

Comment: I'm thinking about use the *ssh* to perform this task, or another jar file listening in some port... I really don't know..